# Quantidade de resultados de pesquisa incorreto

Tags: bug, status-aceito, pesquisa

No SOpt, temos a medalha de [Pergunta Famosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme podemos ver, essa medalha foi concedida 25 vezes.

Fiz uma pesquisa (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A10000) ) de perguntas com mais de 10.000 views e, nos resultados, aparecerem 20 perguntas. Por quê? A quantidade de resultados não deveria ser a mesma do número de vezes que a medalha foi concedida?

---

Por exemplo, [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23537/3117) não aparecia na lista de resultados.

## **Update:**

O pessoal achou o porque que algumas (4) perguntas não apareciam.

Ela só é/era listada quando acontecesse alguma coisa que atualizasse o índice de pesquisa (voto, atualização, etc..).

---

Agora, [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526/) é a única a não aparecer.

Comment: Você acredita que agora tem 21 perguntas na lista e a que apareceu foi justamente a que você linkou aqui? :S

Comment: @Math Então finalmente o SO atingiu a consciência... e ESTÁ DE OLHO

Comment: Medo... ​​​​​​​

Comment: Mudou de novo, realmente parece que o SO atingiu a consciência

Comment: @Gabe mágica!! Coloca as últimas duas que faltam no corpo da pergunta que resolve o bug

Comment: @Math WTF??? #Computers

Comment: É o diabo do SO :D

Comment: Lutando bravamente contra a vontade de adicionar a tag `Bruxaria`

Comment: Editei mais uma vez... Vamos ver se ela aparece lá também

Comment: Aaaah, parte do mistério resolvido: As perguntas não aparecem na busca porque o número de visitas não está sendo atualizado no índice de pesquisa. As perguntas que foram linkadas aqui receberam visitas, que deram upvotes (um foi meu), e o upvote atualizou o índice da pergunta na pesquisa e ela aparece nos resultados.

Comment: @Gabe ou seja, só apareciam no resultado das buscas as perguntas que receberam votos **depois** de atingir o 10k views, é isso?

Comment: @Math votos ou qualquer outra coisa que atualizasse o registro delas no índice de pesquisa. No final das contas, elas estavam "inativas" desde antes de atingirem 10k, e permaneciam assim. Mas porque que receber a medalha não conta como "ativação", só os devs....

Comment: Acho que a tag `Bruxaria` caberia bem.

Comment: *There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.* -- Phil Karlton, apud Martin Fowler

Comment: @Gabe O estranho é que [aqui](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/revision/366027/471742/users-famous-question-badge) eu tenho 24 resultados, e na [descrição da medalha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) me mostra 25. Tem algo errado com minha `query`?

Comment: [Essa não aparece.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6526)

Comment: @Randrade Sua query tá certa, mas o Data Explorer não tem uma base de dados totalmente atualizada. Se você pesquisar por perguntas, vai ver que a mais recente é do dia 13/09. A última "Pergunta Famosa" foi concedida 2 horas atrás.