# Qual o delay do Data Explorer?

Tags: suporte, data-explorer

Ao observar [essa pergunta no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4360/quantidade-de-resultados-de-pesquisa-incorreto), [este comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4360/quantidade-de-resultados-de-pesquisa-incorreto#comment-13572) me chamou atenção:

> [...] o Data Explorer não tem uma base de dados totalmente atualizada. Se você pesquisar por perguntas, vai ver que a mais recente é do dia 13/09. A última "Pergunta Famosa" foi concedida 2 horas atrás.

Após ler isso, gostaria de saber se existe um **"delay padrão¹"** para atualização do [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/queries).

Podemos observar que algumas coisas possuem um certo **delay**, como entrega de medalhas por exemplo. Esse  **delay** é o mesmo que o que o Data Explorer possui?

> ¹ Delay padrão: Um tempo de espera padronizada para que ocorra alguma atualização; Periodicamente; De tempos em tempos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

São duas coisas diferentes.

O Data Explorer tem seus dados atualizados [toda semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq):

> **Com que frequência o Data Explorer é atualizado?**
>   Os dados são atualizados todo domingo de manhã, por volta das 03:00 UTC (00:00 Brasília | 04:00 Lisboa).

Você pode ver a data da última atualização na mesma página.

O delay que causou o bug é diferente. Nosso sistema de busca usa uma indexação diferente e nesse caso a sincronização não funcionou como deveria.

Comment: Nem olhei no FAQ. Vlw Gabe