# Medalhas Intérprete, Aprimorador e Luminar - Como saber quais resposta somaram no status da medalha

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Algumas medalhas precisam completar um número mínimo para serem ganhas.

Como por exemplo a medalha de **Aprimorador** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/116/refiner

Porém não encontrei, *na verdade não sei se existe*, uma forma de acompanhar quais respostas se somaram nessa barra de progresso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No exemplo da imagem acima são `38/50`, teria como eu saber quais são essas `38` respostas que estão somadas na barra?

Não achei referencias no Meta sobre isso...

Comment: Creio que só usando/criando queries no [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que só usando/criando queries no [*Stack Exchange Data Explorer*](https://data.stackexchange.com/), criei este (adaptado de uma outra [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/616090/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge)):

> **Nota:** é importante lembrar que o data explorer tem um delay e os dados nem sempre estão atualizado, pois ele é atualizado apenas no domingo de manhã por volta das 03:00 UTC (00:00 Brasília | 04:00 Lisboa), conforme: [Qual o delay do Data Explorer?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4361/3635)

- [Respostas para as medalhas Intérprete, Aprimorador e Luminar](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/revision/837148/1033168/respostas-para-as-medalhas-interprete-aprimorador-e-luminar)

> **Nota:** não revisei a query, se tiver alguma falha pode avisar

Basta colocar nos campos `userId` o teu ID de usuário do site principal, que fica na URL ou no campo de busca quando acessa o perfil:

[image: id no perfil]

No seu caso é o 97477 que deve ir no campo

A query irá servir para todas seguintes tags:

- Intérprete: Editou e respondeu 1 pergunta (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)  682 concedida
- Aprimorador: Editou e respondeu 50 perguntas (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)  28 concedida
- Luminar: Editou e respondeu 500 perguntas (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)

O nome será em inglês provavelmente, já que foram feitas para os sites em inglês, mas funciona da mesma forma.

Ao fazer a pesquisa com seu ID retornou isto:

[image: postagens para medalha Aprimorador]

Comment: Cara muito legal esse esquema, vi que existem várias outras query interessantes inclusive. Só não achei o resultado muito acurado pq nesse link só retornou perguntas sem pontuação. Mas nesse link funcionou bem, https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/507956/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge repare que ele tem `a.Score >= 0 and ` ai retorna com o score certo das respostas! De qq forma já resolveu! []´s

Comment: @hugocsl revisei a resposta e criei uma query nova baseada na outra que creio ser a correta agora: https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/revision/837148/1033168/respostas-para-as-medalhas-interprete-aprimorador-e-luminar

Comment: Muito bom jovem!! Agora está 100% acurado!